# Quicksort algorithm access violation writing location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, quicksort, access-violation

What is wrong in the implementation of the quicksort algorithm below. The debug reports "access violation writing location". I can't find it. Should I pass the position of the pivot as argument to the `sort` and `partition` functions? This code is based on this interactive online demo: http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

#define LIST_SIZE (UInt)10

typedef uint64_t UInt;

void print(UInt * list, UInt size) {
    for (UInt i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%llu ", list[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void fill(UInt * list, UInt size) {
    for (UInt i = 0; i < size; i++)
        list[i] = (UInt)std::rand();
}

UInt partition(UInt * list, UInt left, UInt right) {
    UInt p = list[left], t = left + 1;

    for (UInt i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (list[i] < p) {
            std::swap(list[i], list[t]);
            t++;
        }
    }

    std::swap(p, list[t]);

    return t;
}

void sort(UInt * list, UInt left, UInt right) {
    UInt p;

    if (left < right) {
        p = partition(list, left, right);

        sort(list, left, p - 1);
        sort(list, p + 1, right);
    }
}

void quicksort(UInt * list, UInt size) {
    sort(list, 0, size - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    UInt list[LIST_SIZE];

    fill(list, LIST_SIZE);
    print(list, LIST_SIZE);
    quicksort(list, LIST_SIZE);
    print(list, LIST_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: get some debug prints happening and make sure each step is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Definitely run this code through a debugger and single-step through it to make sure it does what you think it does.  Pay particular attention to the return value of `partition()`. Another useful technique is to `assert()` assumptions which will break the program if false, such as the partition value being between `left` and `right`.

Comment: I looked at your programm with a debugger and it looks to be broken. The segfault happens very deep in the stack trace (recursion depth at ~400).

Answer (score 1):

The following change does the trick for you. In the for loop, you have to check for i < right. If you do a <= there, you wont make progress in some circumstances. However, i did not check if you algorithm is correct in every respect now.

```
UInt partition(UInt * list, UInt left, UInt right) {
    UInt p = list[left], t = left + 1;

    for (UInt i = left + 1; i < right; i++) {
        if (list[i] < p) {
            std::swap(list[i], list[t]);
            t++;
        }
    }

    std::swap(p, list[t]);

    return t;
}
```